# Why is my JFrame not resizing?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jlist

I have specified the width and height with `f.setSize();` but it is not making any difference.

Here is the code:

```
public class MTGSAMPServerReference extends JPanel{

    public static Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(); 
    static int ScrnWidth = ((int) tk.getScreenSize().getWidth());
    static int ScrnHeight = ((int) tk.getScreenSize().getHeight());

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MTGSAMPServerReference gui = new MTGSAMPServerReference();
        gui.launchFrame();
    }

    public void launchFrame() {
        String[]listContents={"Vehicles","Houses","Companies","Objects","Jobs"};
        JFrame f = new JFrame("MTG SAMP Server Reference");
        JList list1=new JList(listContents);
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            f.setVisible(true);
            f.setSize(1200, 800);
            f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            f.add(list1);
            list1.setSize(500, 500);
            Container contentPaneMain = f.getContentPane();
            contentPaneMain.add(new MTGSAMPServerReference());
            f.pack();
        }
}
```

What is it that I am doing wrong, or forgetting?

Comment: You can either use `pack()` or `setSize()`

Comment: I have used both those, and have been told by others to put `pack()` at the end of my GUI code, as I have done. But what am I missing?

Comment: Use `setSize(400,400)` instead of `pack()`.

Comment: Oh I got it, I just had to put `pack();` before `setSize();` Thanks!

Comment: Please delete this question @knorberg

Comment: @AVD if you post that as an answer, i'll upvote it

Comment: @AVD  `pack()` should *always* be called even when `setSize(..)` is the very next statement.  It does more than 'set the size'.

Comment: See also [*Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513)?

Comment: @WilliamMorrison Why would I delete this question?

Comment: Its been solved with no posts? Been nice to give rep to someone but as there are no answers...